# Translations not working remotely only in a local environment

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, internationalization, asp.net-core-2.2

On my browser that I run from my local environemnt, the strings are translated as supposed to. When I upload to Azure, it still works. However, when I switch to Edge (that I never use for anything other than downloading FireFox), the strings are not translated anymore. I verified with external users on a wide range of browsers and it seems be platform independent issue.

I have all my translations in a global file placed in the root directory and I have the dummy file so I can inject it into views and controllers, as proposed by the docs. Somehow, the RESX file seems not to be found so I put it to *Always upload*. No change in misbehavior, though.

I'm not sure how to diagnose it further or if the RESX file is compiled into the DLL or uploaded straight off to the server and read from on the fly. Is it possible to verify that the file is "up there" somehow?

My config is like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddLocalization(a => a.ResourcesPath = "");

  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(a =>
    {
      CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = {
        new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
        new CultureInfo("se")
      };
      a.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("se");
      a.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      a.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
  ...
  services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
  ...
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

**edit**

I've noticed that it works in Chrome when I have those lines.

```
RequestLocalizationOptions options = app.ApplicationServices
  .GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

It stops working when I have those instead.

```
  //RequestLocalizationOptions options = app.ApplicationServices
  //  .GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

In IE it doesn't work in either case.

Comment: Are you using cookie localization? It's possible (but I'm not sure) that something wrong with cookies in Edge. So try to specify culture via query string and see if it works in Edge.

Comment: @Alexander I see I wasn't clear on the issue. The strings are not translated in any browser unless that browser has been used "since before". Not sure how long but I run my stuff in Cr and FF usually and it worked on my computer. However, the same browsers on another computer fail. And to make it more weird, even local run in IE and Eg fail. But just to exclude the possibility that it's something with cookies - how would I go about specifying the cookie according to your suggestion?

Comment: Okay if it was something wrong with cookie you still should've seen translation for default culture (`se` in your case). It's kinda weird that it works in one browser and doesn't in another because browser doesn't affect localization process (well, it only sets request culture, that's all). And if it worked before and doesn't work now you must've changed something in the project, specifically localization files. And what is *dummy file*? What's the name of your file with localizations?

Comment: have you changed this startup code? Granted you said this is working but I would have expected the RequestLocalizationOptions service to be passed into UseRequestLocalization. Like  var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

Comment: @Alexander Excellent points. It has worked and works **still** in Cr and FF (both locally and remotely). It doesn't work in Eg and IE (loco and remo). I'm currently asking people to install browsers and check on their systems. It looks as if the browsers used originally in development chached something... As for the dummy - it's just an empty class that I use when injecting *IStringLocalization<Lingo>*. My RESX file is called *Ling.se.resx* (I also created *Controller.Lingo.se.resx* in pure deperation). I want to keep all the translation in a single file for now for practical reasons. Help?

Comment: @eVolve I'll try that right away. I'm still a bit confused about the localization á la .NET Core so I might have done something quite stupid. I did notice a warning, though, saying that request localization middleware gave *AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider returned the following unsupported cultures 'en-US, en, sv'* in **all** the browsers.

Comment: @Alexander Please see the edit in the question. I've noticed something that **might** implicate the source of error if someone is wise enough.

Comment: Theres still a lack of detail in the question to diagnose the problem. First identify which method of localization you want your app to work with. Based off what you have said I would suspect your app is using AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider and in order to get this working in IE / Edge you should Set the Accept-Language HTTP header. @Alexander mentioned about cookie localization and is another method of allowing a culture to be set. This link describes them and also shows cookie localization https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/

Comment: You edit made it mode weird because you don't need to pass anything to ` app.UseRequestLocalization()` if you did `services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>`. The DI does everything for you.

Comment: @Alexander You are right. It's really weird because it shouldn't behave that way. I suspect that I, in my ignorance, describe it in a misleading way (stating true facts but perhaps in a wrong way, possibly omitting something relevant). Let me poke around and get back. For now, I made it "work" bu skipping *app.UseRequestLocalization()* (which forces it to go for the default RESX, i.e. *Lingo.resx* in all browsers). It's going to hold as long I only use Swedish, which is hardly a satisfying globalization, hehe. As it looks now, using the *app.UseXxx* fails to point to the right file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple words about culture configuration. I guess you wanted to specify only Swedish locale so you have these line of code

```
CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = {
    new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
    new CultureInfo("se")
};
```

It turns out that `sv-SE` is definitely *Swedish* culture, but `se` is *Northern Sami* culture. If your intention is only *Swedish* culture you need to set `sv` instead of `se`

```
CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = {
    new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
    new CultureInfo("sv")
};
a.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sv");
```

Back to the main problem. By default there are 3 ways to set request culture, via query string, cookies or `Accept-Language` header. It looks like you don't specify a culture in request cookies or query string, but your browser sends `Accept-Language` header from which ASP.NET Core reads request culture. If a browser sends `en-US`, `en`, and `sv` cultures, none of them matches to `supportedCultures` (which are `sv-SE` and `se`) the framework falls back to `DefaultRequestCulture` (which is `se`) and reads resources from `Lingo.se.resx` and everything is fine. But it looks like Edge (on any other browser but on another computer) sent different set of cultures within `Accept-Language` header which included `sv-SE` containing in `supportedCultures`. So resource reader searched for `Lingo.sv-se.resx` or `Lingo.sv.resx` file but with no luck and thus no translation were provided.

If my assumption is right changing `se` to `sv` in your code and renaming `Lingo.se.resx` to `Lingo.sv.resx` will fix the problem.